# CCSprite shader program leaves 1px transparent border

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, tmx, tiled

I'm developing a game where the players can drag and drop `CCSprite`s around an **Isometric** map which is created using the Tiled Map Editor.

To allow automatic vertexZ reordering I have enabled the `depthTest` option of `[CCDirector sharedDirector]` in my `AppDelegate`.

Whenever the `CCSprite`s `position`s are updated i call this function

```
- (void)updateVertexZ:(CGPoint)tilePos tileMap:(CCTMXTiledMap *)tileMap
{
    float lowestZ = -(tileMap.mapSize.width + tileMap.mapSize.height);
    float currentZ = tilePos.x + tilePos.y;
    self.vertexZ = lowestZ + currentZ;
}
```

which correctly reorders the sprites.

Whenever such a sprite is instantiated, I set the `shaderProgram` like this:

```
self.shaderProgram = [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache]programForKey:kCCShader_PositionTextureColorAlphaTest];
```

Now, when two sprites are aligned like this (x being a sprite, 0 being empty):

```
0 x 
x 0
```

and are observed from an **Isometric** perspective. They are indeed placed correctly. 
However along the first(closest) sprite a 1px-border is visible - see image. It is the floor in the background - not very cool.

[image]

Why is this border visible and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Don't know the solution but it looks like you have a blend mode problem.

Comment: Cheers Steffen, semi-solved using [self.texture setAliasParameters]

Comment: you may need to sort the tiles from back to fron

Comment: How do i do that efficiently?